# AWS ApiGateway Host header & Custom domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

When using `AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName`, it creates hidden `CloudFront` distribution to actually fetch custom domain name. The problem is that when passing original request down to something like `ELB`, original headers are lost, including Host header. I need Host header in my application that is deployed in `ECS`.

Possible solution is to create `Lambda@Edge` function that adds `X-Forwarded-Host` header and maps it to the value of Host header. The problem is that I cannot figure out how to create Lambda Function Association on hidden `Cloudfront` distribution that `ApiGateway` creates.

Is there actually a possibility to have Host header preserved in `ApiGateway` with Custom Domain name setup, as for now?

Comment: Just with any header you want sent to the origin, you need to configure it to be passed in API gateway.

Comment: Thank you. All I needed was to add Host header in Resources => HTTP Request Headers.

Answer (score -2):

You can whitelist any header to be sent to the origin. Configure the `Host` header for forwarding in your API Gateway configuration.